# In R, how can I group a dataframe based on a number and its negative counterpart?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe

```
structure(list(ID = c("8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", "8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", 
"8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", "8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494"
), Home = c("Los Angeles Dodgers", "Los Angeles Dodgers", "Los Angeles Dodgers", 
"Los Angeles Dodgers"), Away = c("Washington Nationals", "Washington Nationals", 
"Washington Nationals", "Washington Nationals"), Team = c("Los Angeles Dodgers", 
"Los Angeles Dodgers", "Washington Nationals", "Washington Nationals"
), Points = c(-2.5, -1.5, 1.5, 2.5), Price = c(119, -140, 135, 
-128)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(ID = c("8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", 
"8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", "8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494", 
"8d3d8275bc3dd5b45aa13dc8fb3fe494"), Points = c(-2.5, -1.5, 1.5, 
2.5), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I am trying to run some computations but need to be able to group based on the Points observation and it's opposite value prior to running the computations.  So using the provided dput I would have two groups of (-2.5 and 2.5) and (-1.5 and 1.5).  How can I go about grouping in this manner?

Comment: `group_by(Pts_abs = abs(Points)) %>% `